commands undefinde (name_localization: )
I try to make a discord bot with javascript. My problem is that the commands in discord don`t function. Can someone help me to fix this issue?
This is my error:
/applications/1235114104566579231/guilds/1183059923391754411/commands {
  body: [
    {
      options: [],
      name: 'ping',
      name_localizations: undefined,
      description: 'Return my ping!',
      description_localizations: undefined,
      default_permission: undefined,
      default_member_permissions: undefined,
      dm_permission: undefined,
      nsfw: undefined
    }
  ]
}

This is my code:
ping.js (command)
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('ping')
        .setDescription('Return my ping!'),
    async execute(interaction, client) {
        const message = await interaction.deferReply({
            fetchReply: true
        });

        const newMessage = `API Latency: ${client.ws.ping}\nClient Ping: ${message.createdTimestamp - interaction.createdTimestamp}`
        await interaction.editReply({
            content: newMessage
        });
    }
}

InteractionCreate.js
module.exports = {
    name: 'interactionCreate',
    async execute(interaction, client) {
        if (interaction.isChatInputCommand()) {
            const { commands } = client;
            const { commandName } = interaction;
            const command = commands.get(commandName);
            if (!command) return;

            try {
                await command.execute(interaction, client);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error);
                await interaction.reply({
                    content: `Something went wrong while executing this command...`,
                    ephemeral: true,
                });
            }
        }
    },
};

ready.js
module.exports = {
    name: 'ready',
    once: true,
    async execute(client) {
        console.log(`Ready ${client.user.tag} is logged in and online`);
    }
}

handlecommands.js
const { REST } = require('@discordjs/rest');
const { Routes } = require('discord-api-types/v9');

const fs = require('fs');

module.exports = (client) => {
    client.handleCommands = async () => {
        const commandFolders = fs.readdirSync('./commands');
        for (const folder of commandFolders) {
            const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(
                `./commands/${folder}`)
                .filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

            const { commands, commandArray } = client;
            for (const file of commandFiles) {
                const command = require(`../../commands/${folder}/${file}`);
                commands.set(command.data.name, command);
                commandArray.push(command.data.toJSON());
            }
        }

        const clientId = '1235114104566579231';
        const guildId = '1183059923391754411';
        const rest = new REST({ version: '9' }).setToken(process.env.token);
        try {
            console.log(Routes.applicationGuildCommands(clientId, guildId), {
                body: client.commandArray,
            });

            console.log("Successfully reloaded application (/) commands.");
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    };
};

handleEvents.js
const fs = require('fs');

module.exports = (client) => {
    client.handleEvents = async () => {
        const eventFolders = fs.readdirSync(`./events`);
        for (const folder of eventFolders) {
            const eventFiles = fs.readdirSync(
                `./events/${folder}`)
                .filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
            switch (folder) {
                case "client":
                    for (const file of eventFiles) {
                        const event = require(`../../events/${folder}/${file}`);
                        if (event.once) client.once(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args, client));
                        else client.on(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args, client));
                    }
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    };
};

bot.js (index)
require('dotenv').config();

const { token } = process.env;
const { Client, Collection, GatewayIntentBits } = require("discord.js");
const fs = require("fs");

const client = new Client({ intents: GatewayIntentBits.Guilds });
client.commands = new Collection();
client.commandArray = [];

const functionFolders = fs.readdirSync(`./functions`);
for (const folder of functionFolders) {
    const functionFiles = fs
        .readdirSync(`./functions/${folder}`)
        .filter((file) => file.endsWith('.js'))
    for (const file of functionFiles) require(`./functions/${folder}/${file}`)(client);
}

client.handleEvents();
client.handleCommands();
client.login(token);

package.json
  "name": "erstesprojekt",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "bot.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "node ."
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "Luis Schroeder",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@discordjs/rest": "^2.2.0",
    "chalk": "^4.1.2",
    "discord-api-types": "^0.37.83",
    "discord.js": "^14.14.1",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5"
  }
}

Can someone help`s me to fix this error?

It seems like your bot is missing permissions. Can you try looking at the intents you have allowed both on dev portal and in your index.js file. You need to add members and messages permissions. That should solve the error from what I can think. Also instead of gateway intents bits, try using intents bit field works better.
